# if condition is not working properly in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a very simple shell script like below which is supposed to basically connect to a remote server and just counts lines at its root directory, compares with zero & prints output like given below but it the if condition always gives the error:

> integer expression expected

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=servername
var1=$(ssh username@$i -t "cd /;ls -l|wc -l" 2>/dev/null)
echo $var1   #(gives me a number output e.g 28)
if [ $var1 -gt 0 ]
then
echo "successfuly connected"
else
echo "failed to connect"
fi
```

Comment: "urgently" on SO is inappropriate.

Comment: If you can use bash (`#!/bin/bash`) then replace the if statement with `if [[ $var1 -gt 0 ]]`

Answer (score 1):

There may be other (possibly invisible) characters in the output of your ssh command.

Try passing that output through sed to strip all non-digits:

```
var1=$(ssh username@$i -t "cd /;ls -l|wc -l" 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because either nothing is being assigned to var1 or var1 contains extra characters. `wc` is a bugger for this, it prints everything indented to a specific place so what I usually do is pipe this through awk to get just the number.

try:

```
var1=$(ssh username@$i -- "cd /; ls -l | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data probably contains a trailing carriage return. I can reproduce the error:

```
$ /bin/sh
sh-4.2$ var1=28
sh-4.2$ [ $var1 -gt 0 ]
sh-4.2$ [ $var1 -gt 0 ] && echo OK
OK
sh-4.2$ var1=28^M
sh-4.2$ [ $var1 -gt 0 ]
: integer expression expected
```

The `^M` is a literal carriage return, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

To verify your data:

```
printf "%s" "$var1" | od -c
```

Use @Nate's or @mplf's advice to trim the unwanted chars.

Answer (score -2):

it should be written like this

```
if [ "$var1" > "0" ]
```

look at http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html under 
7.1.2.2. Numeric comparisons

whole file

```
#!/bin/sh
i=servername
var1=$(ssh username@$i -t "ls -l|wc -l" 2>/dev/null)
echo $var1
if [ "$var1" > "0" ]
then
echo "successfuly connected"
else
echo "failed to connect"
fi
```

gives me

```
29
successfuly connected
```

Comment: quoting doesn't help and you should not quote integer comparisons. You only need to quote the variables if you're doing a string comparison.

Comment: using the exact line i provided works, using his gives the error listed. So its clearly working

Comment: OP is probably getting a \r character along with the output which won't be solved by your answer. It might be working fine on your machine